# Java Cyclic Generics

Tags: java, generics

How can I get type safety for a set of classes when there are cyclic relationships.  I have 3 classes, Router, Interactor and Component such that

```
abstract class Router<C extends Component, I extends Interactor>
abstract class Interactor<R extends Router>
abstract class Component<I extends Interactor>
```

I want to ensure that a specific router is tied to a specific component and specific interactor.

**Edit** The architecture of the app ensures that we have exactly 1 router for 1 interactor for 1 component. Some reuse is possible but if router A is with interactor A and component A it will always be that way, otherwise we would define router B with interactor A and component B for example.

**Edit 2** A more concrete example: 
We can have the login screen which has loginscreenrouter, loginscreeninteractor and loginscreencomponent and then the loading screen which has 3 more classes in the same structure. But what we don't want is for developers to accidentally pass the loadingscreeninteractor to the loginscreenrouter

Comment: What is the real use case? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Could you use a different “tag” type for each triple and use it as an argument to each?

Comment: Do you in fact need these to be generic at all?  All of them?

Comment: @lalo the architecture of our system is a hierarchy of components, and each component has at least these 3 classes.  For example we can have the login screen which has loginscreenrouter, loginscreeninteractor and loginscreencomponent and then the loading screen which has 3 more classes in the same structure.  But what we don't want is for developers to accidentally pass the loadingscreeninteractor to the loginscreenrouter

Comment: @Zachary you should [edit] your post to include your latest comment. That comment contains important information to understand the question, especially the concrete example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each type will need a parameter for each of the types including itself.

```
abstract class Router<
    R extends Router<R,C,I>, C extends Component<R,C,I>, I extends Interactor<R,C,I>
> { }

abstract class Interactor<
    R extends Router<R,C,I>, C extends Component<R,C,I>, I extends Interactor<R,C,I>
> { }

abstract class Component<
    R extends Router<R,C,I>, C extends Component<R,C,I>, I extends Interactor<R,C,I>
>  { }
```

I guess another way around, that I haven't seen before, is to push all the interactions into one type. Less angles, but doesn't feel very OO and perhaps causes more work.

```
import java.util.Set;

interface System<R extends Router, C extends Component, I extends Interactor> {
    Set<R> routers(I interactor);
    Set<R> routers(C component);
    Set<I> interactors(R router);
    Set<I> interactors(C component);
    Set<C> components(R router);
    Set<C> components(I interactor);
}

abstract class Router {}

abstract class Interactor {}

abstract class Component { }
```

Comment: For the first method won't we then end up in an infinite cycle LoginRouter<LoginRouter<LoginRouter<LoginRouter ...

For the second method why do we have to break up Set<R> routers(I interactor); and  Set<R> routers(C component); ? 

I guess I should have clarified that there is a 1:1:1 setup for each component, I'll edit the post

Comment: No, works like an `enum`, `class LoginRouter extends Router<LoginRouter, LoginComponent, LoginInteractor> {` - none of those type arguments are generic types themselves. `Set` is just there as an illustration - this sort of problem usually arises with (graph theory) graphs.

Comment: So if I use the first one, the base class doesn't know it's R in the generics so if we have a method on the interactor `setRouter(R router)` we can't use `this` is there any way around that?

Comment: @ZacharySweigart Another common issue: You add a method to `Router`: `protected abstract R getThis();`. Implement it as `protected LoginRouter getThis() { return this; } ` in leaf classes.